# How big should a macOS Big Sur 11.4 Download be from Big Sur 11.2?

Tags: macos, software-update

My 13" MacBook Pro 2015 is running macOS Big Sur 11.2.2. I am updating to Big Sur 11.4 and the updater has downloaded nearly 18 gigabytes of data already.

Is something wrong?

Comment: From **Software Update** in **System Preferences** on  **macOS Big Sur** 11.2.2 it shows it as: **macOS Big Sur 11.4 11.4 5.73 GB**.

Comment: How are you measuring 18 GB? The installer downloads in chunks and then validates the download so It could be expected if you have network issues or have to redownload a lot of the sections.

Comment: I have an application that tracks how much data has been downloaded over the course of the day. I split it so it kept track of just the download and had no other applications open.

Comment: for comparison - Currently updating a new M1 iMac from 11.3 to 11.4 - download size is 12.38GB Reported size hasn't changed since it started, download at 11GB right now… but by heck, it's slow, 4 hours & counting. I could have got 12GB of 'random internet movie' in about 20 minutes. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMqOd.png [I don't know if the size changed between seeing the update was available & actually requesting it to download. Just wasn't paying attention] The extra few GB wouldn't seem anomalous, by comparison.

Comment: It got to about 40gb before I had to shut it off and start being productive again.

Comment: If you're using WiFi, switch to Ethernet. Mine ended shortly after my last comment with just the same figure it had claimed from the start. Yes it was 'too slow to catch cold' but it did work as promised. [I have subsequently, for other purposes, downloaded a full Mojave installer which I got inside 10 minutes. I've no idea why the internal updater mechanism is so slow in Big Sur]

Comment: @user3439894 How can you see the download on your system preferences?

Comment: Peter Nielsen, From **System Preferences** > **Software Update**, click the **More Info…** _link_, and then it will show on the ensuing _sheet_, as in these [screen shots](https://imgur.com/a/fzDzKA2).